# Iterate over clojure map pairs (loop)

Tags: loops, dictionary, clojure

I have a sequence of map-pairs like this (currently about 17000 pairs)

```
(def myseq '({:name "Peter" :rank 2222} {:name "Anna" :rank 111}))
```

I want to filter specific pairs into a new sequence with

```
(filter (fn [x] (> x 222)) (:rank (first myseq)))
```

I have been trying to iterate with loop like this but keep getting thread-death. Also if I use filter on a a single map collection it just returns a new sequence, not sure if I need to create one myself here?

```
(defn remove-lower [number myseq]
    (loop [i 0]
        (if (= i (count file))
            (println "done")
            (filter [x] (> x number))
                (:rank (first myseq))))
    (recur (rest myseq))))
```

Finally is looping the most efficient way to get the new sequence of pairs?

Answer (score 8):

No need for loop/recur here. filter already iterates through a seq for you:

```
(filter (fn [entry] (> (:rank entry) 220)) myseq)
```

Comment: Even better ! Thats how I tried to do it first but did not succeed .Thanks.

Comment: `(filter #(> (:rank %) 220) myseq)`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, the code is now working and very fast too!

Answer (score 6):

First thing to know is that (most of) the data structures in clojure are immutable and most functions are, well, *functional*. That means, that they don't have side effects. In your case `filter` doesn't change the sequence in any way, it returns a new one, containing only the unfiltered items.

So, to filter `myseq` you need to do something like:

```
(def filtered-seq (filter (fn [x] ...) myseq))
```

Filter will call the function repeatedly, binding `x`to the currently filtered item in `myseq`. That is, the first time it'll be bound to `{:name "Peter" :rank 2222}`, then to `{:name "Anna" :rank 111}`. The `filtered-seq` will contain only the elements, for which the function returned true. `myseq` will *not* be modified!

So, you want to leave only elements with `:rank` higher than 222:

```
(filter (fn [x] (> (:rank x) 222)) myseq)
```

That's it. And one more thing about filter is, that it's lazy. That is, items in the returned collection are "realized" (or computed) only when they are needed.

You don't need to use `loop` for this, as `filter` does the job nicely, and `loop` isn't lazy.

That said, your `loop` doesn't work because it has several problems:

1. `recur` is outside the `loop`. In this case clojure will loop back to the beginning of the function.
2. you need to construct a return value and you need to maintain the "current" element
3. you need to properly check for the end condition

The code could look something like this (untested):

```
(defn remove-lower [number myseq]
  (loop [sq myseq res []]
     (if (empty? sq)
         res
         (let [current (first sq)]
           (if (> (:rank current) number)
              (recur (rest sq) (conj res current))
              (recur (rest sq) res))))))
```

Note how:

1. `recur` is now inside the `loop`
2. `res` contains the return value and `sq` contains the currently left sequence
3. each `recur` passes the new values of `sq` and `res` for the next iteration
4. `sq` is "shrinked" with each iteration, so the loop will eventually exit unless `myseq` is infinite. Contrast this to `filter`, which handles infinite sequences just fine.

As you see this is harder to read and less general than `filter` and also is eager (not lazy).